# Is "Codable Firestore" supported by Apple?

Tags: ios, app-store, codable, swift5

I have been using "Codable Firestore" in iOS project.

Is this supported by Apple, if I upload build on Appstore?

**Codable Firestore :** https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase

Comment: CodableFirebase is just like other 3rd party libraries. Apple only restrict apps that access private APIs. So you can upload your app on AppStore as long as it don't access private APIs

Comment: @udbhateja Thanks for sharing your knowledge. But my question is specifically for "CodableFirestore"

Comment: For 'CodableFirebase', Apple is not going to reject your app.